# How To Save A Value from TextBox In MS Access 2010

Tags: forms, ms-access

Good day,

In my Ms Access 2010 Form, I have 4 textboxes, namely GrossAmt, WTax1, WTax2, and NetAmt.

GrossAmt, WTax1, and WTax2 are bounded. And so, their values are stored in the table.

NetAmt is unbounded as I have a function running. In its Control Source I have this:

```
=[GrossAmount]-([WTax1]+[WTax2]).
```

which is running properly. My problem is, how can I save the value(answer) in the table?

I have tried adding another textbox (named NetAmount) which is bounded to the table and was supposed to copy the values from the unbounded textbox. I have tried putting Me.NetAmount = Me.NetAmt in the "After Update" Event in Property but its not saving.

What should I do, I don't have any clue on what to do anymore. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the equals sign, the value is not stored anywhere, it is calculated on the fly.

If `GrosssAmount`, `WTax1` & `WTax2` are stored in the database you never need to store that data, instead you can run the calculation based on the other three. In fact, I would recommend that you do it this way, unless there is a particular need to retrieve a historic net amount.

If you wanted to save the data to the database, you're going to have to use code on Update. 
the easiest would be to write a function, something like

```
Private Function saveNetAmount()
    Me.[NetAmount] = [GrossAmount]-([WTax1]+[WTax2])
End Function
```

and then add that into the AfterUpdate or OnChange event for the Gross Amount, WTax1 and WTax2 text boxes.

Something like:

```
Private Sub GrossAmt_AfterUpdate()
    Call saveNetAmount
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to retrieve the Net Amount in the Report associated with the form, that is why I really need to save the it. In what textbox will I need to put 

    " Private Function saveNetAmount()
    Me.[NetAmount] = [GrossAmount]-([WTax1]+[WTax2])
    End Function "